# Why are "homework" and "work" uncountable in English?

Tags: nouns, history, uncountable-nouns

In Bulgarian both "homework" and "work" are countable. Why are they uncountable in English then? What is the difference in meaning that makes that happen?

Comment: 'Why'?' is a difficult question. Sometimes things just _are_.

Answer (score 11):

Both are considered [**mass nouns**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), just like *milk*, *air*, etc.

However, *work* can also refer to a singular piece of creation (art, literature, plays, etc.), in which case it can be pluralized:

> These are all the *works* of Shakespeare.

If you want to refer to a specific part of your *work*, you could use *task*:

> I completed twelve *tasks*. I got a lot of *work* done today.

Likewise, if you want to refer to a single, discrete unit of *homework*, use *assignment*:

> Our teacher gave us three *assignments* to complete by Friday.